# HTML data entry

Tags: php, html, data-entry

I have gotten a project on my desk. It involves updating the bios for a bunch of people, however, my boss does not want into a database (I think that would be the best solution but lets not go there). Although, he never said anything about flat files! :)

So, my solution would be to create a PHP page with some form elements with like "Education" and a text area for it, "Awards" and a textarea ect. and just turn the plaintext into a semblance of HTML.

I was wondering if anyone had any other better ideas?

The formats look similar to:

[center]
name
address[/center]

education: blah blah blah

Awards: blah blah

Edit 1: Eventually we will want people to be able to update their own bios.

Comment: Why turn it into "a semblance" of html?  Why not use full html?

Comment: I use a template system so all I really need to do is turn the newlines to line breaks and turn certain symbols into HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what is going to happen with the data, I'd say. What is the purpose? Just displaying it on the very same web page? I.e. a very minimalistic wiki?
There are several compact wiki implementations out there, without database also, perhaps one of the might suit your needs?

EDIT: [Some Wikis compared](http://www.wikimatrix.org/)

Comment: Well, we have already created our own custom system in PHP using the layout that was given to us so all we have to do is plug in data (HTML). For the template system we are using smarty. I guess the question is more what would be the easiest, yet best, way to get the bios into the system yet allow for future expandbility.

Comment: Hmmm I think you should stick with saving it to text or xml files, then.